# How can I redraw an svg path to fit the width of its contianer?

Tags: jquery, svg

I am just beginning to work with svg' and am struggling a bit. I have an svg that I want to take up 50% of the browser window.

**html**

```
<svg id="abstract-shape" width="720px" height="803px" viewBox="0 0 720 803" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet" version="1.1"
                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient x1="54.0357258%" y1="64.0162942%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="linearGradient-1">
                        <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" offset="0%"></stop>
                        <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="0" offset="100%"></stop>
         </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g id="abstract-shape-group" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"
                   transform="translate(0.000000, -221.000000)" opacity="0.05">
    <g id="left-column" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)">
                        <path d="M-5.68434189e-14,221.50221 C51.2277861,495.264742 134.633326,688.315239 250.21662,800.653703 C365.799915,912.992168 522.394374,883.015785 720,710.724555 L720,1024 L-5.68434189e-14,1024 L-5.68434189e-14,221.50221 Z"
                              id="shape"></path>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Here is how I am listening for the resize event. I am also firing the resize method right when the dom is ready.

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    var $body = $('body'),
        $window = $(window);


function setSvgCoverSize() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight(),
        windowWidth = $(window).innerWidth(),
        halfWindowWidth = (Math.floor(windowWidth / 2));

    $('#abstract-shape')
        .removeAttr('viewBox').attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + halfWindowWidth + ' ' + windowHeight)
        .removeAttr('height').attr('height', windowHeight + 'px')
        .removeAttr('width').attr('width', halfWindowWidth + 'px');
}

setSvgCoverSize();

...

$window.resize(function () {
    setSvgCoverSize();
});


...
```

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/damonjentree/pen/wyLWPq) of what I am trying (and failing miserably) at.

Thank you for any suggestions!

**EDIT**

My apologies for not attaching a screen shot, here is what the current functionality is doing. As you can see, the "swoop" thing is only stretching *about* 50% of the way.
[image]

Comment: What isn't working? (what is the current behaviour), do you have any console error?

Comment: Sorry Liora - I didn't think to attach a screen shot to go along with my code. I'm not getting any errors, just not having much luck making the "swoop" shape resize itself to always be the same width as the blue-grey area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is cause by the `preserveAspectRatio` and the `viewBox` propreties of your svg

The `viewBox` proprety is here to make sure that no matter the width/height of the svg, the items inside are still at the same place. In your case, you don't want to change this value even when the browser is resized. You can simply remove this line :

```
.removeAttr('viewBox').attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + halfWindowWidth + ' ' + windowHeight)
```

And then, you don't want to preserve the aspect ratio, since you want it to expand according to the size, so you can set `preserveAspectRatio="none"`

Demo here -> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQeRVv

Comment: How can I buy you a drink!!! Thank you so much - this is the shove in the right direction I should have asked at the beginning of the day.

Comment: Glad I could help :)